# How can I do language packs on my Discord Bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, discord.py

I'm developping a Discord Bot (some of you may already know it), and I wanted to do "language packs", text files where I store all sentences and words used by the bot in different languages.
But here's my problem.

I'm trying to import the "English" file in a list and print the list's content on Discord. That's easy, but then I try to reimport the list, but with another text file ("French") and it doesn't work.

I tried to use the "prefix" code, based on the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
with open("language.json") as f:
    language = json.load(f)
default_language = "EN"

def language(bot, message):
    id = message.server.id
    return language.get(id, default_language)


lang = [i.strip() for i in open(#UNFINISHED)]#import each lines of the file [lang = [i.strip() for i in open(language).readlines()]]
```

I expected this code to import the language file the user selected (english default) but I get a TypeError.
I asked help to a friend, he told me to use `aiofiles`, but I don't know what it is and/or how to use it. He didn't know how to solve this problem.

==================================EDIT=====================================

I moved to Discord.py Rewrite because I was stuck on something. So I'm making the bot again, with some difficulties, but I'm still planning to add these translations.

But this time it is more complex. I use cogs, and these cogs will need to be translated too.

N.B. : As I don't find many tutorials on rewrite version, I'll probably ask more questions in the future.

Comment: Your friend is referring to https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles/. Can you edit your question to include the TypeError?

Comment: You're using the same identifier for the json object `language` and the function `language`, so the latter will  overwrite the former.

Comment: just found how to do it. It's a little bit complex but it works